# How to block packets after capturing?

Tags: iptables, tcpdump, packet-capture

I use tcpdump to capture output packets for one server, but I also need to block these packets.

If I use iptables to block them, then I also can not capture anything.

Can I block packets with iptables and still capture the packets before they are dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a passive (un-addressed) interface to capture, and a second interface (addressed) to block.

To setup an interface for capture, without an address, you do:
`ifconfig eth0 up`

You may need to hack on your switch to make this all fly, but the essence is: mirror all traffic to both interfaces (i.e. switch ports), and then capture on the one, and filter on the other.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand, you want to block connection but capture packets.

you can do this by using MARKS

for example if you want block connection for host 192.168.10.1 with connection 192.168.10.2(*nix) you can do with this

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.10.1 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -m connmark --mark 1 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks! Can i block gre packets but can capture them with this rule ?

Comment: but i can capture input packets, but can not capture the output packets :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fairly simple snort ruleset to "log" packets as well as drop or refuse them: [Snort](http://www.snort.org/). However, there are several prerequisites and it is yet another syntax to learn so there is quite an overhead. [Snort :: Docs](http://www.snort.org/docs) has quick-start guides for several different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot block packets on the raw socket, because there is no filter for it currently. Above all, the raw socket gets the packet, in fact, even *a copy of the packet*, before the IPv4 tap and iptables do get theirs.